# Where is the logout button located?

Tags: support

I'm on a public computer and I logged in to stacX. 
Now I need to log out - but where is the logout button?

Comment: Hover over your username at the top of the page. The popup will feature a log out link.

Comment: Click the little arrow next to your name or just hover over your name.

Comment: Ah, now I see it. I did click my name / arrow, but could still not see the logout button. This is poor usability. Either highlight the logout button or even better, place it next to `faq` menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hover the mouse over your name in the title, the logout link is there:

[image: logout]

Answer (score 0):

If you press on the small triangle next to your username you get a new window. On the top of that window there are 3 links: activity, privileges and log out.